# Can I replace my laptop's processor for a better one, despite being 22nm instead of 32nm?

Tags: laptop, cpu

I have an old ACER 5830TG but that is very good for what I do (Web development).

However, I was thinking in upgrading it rather than buying a new one.

It comes with an `Intel i5 2410m`, and apart from buying 16gb of ram (specs says only up to 8gb but I'm gonna try) and an SSD for it, I was thinking in upgrading the processor, by buying an `Intel Core i7-3632QM`. It has the same socket, uses the same TDP (35w) but differs in microns (32 vs 22).

Will it work?

Comment: Usually, Processors are welded to the board.  This is most likely not possible.

Comment: @CheesusCrust Quite often yes, but not in this case. There is G2 socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your laptop has chipset Intel HM65 with Socket G2/rPGA988B. According to Intel pages it isn't compatible with your desired Core i7-3632QM.

Click on compatible products:

https://ark.intel.com/products/52808/Mobile-Intel-HM65-Express-Chipset

But be carefull. Your CPU is 35W model so higher 45W CPUs would most probably overheat!

Answer (score 2):

You can change the processor on many computers provided 3 things:

1. You can actually remove the processor
2. The socket is compatible
3. The motherboard is compatible

You can check for information on the last 2 points by using some tool like CPU-z or similar which will thell you the model and capabilities of both, and you can further inspect their compatibility on the manufacturer's website.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I've reduced the search to i7-3610QE or it-2860QM then, Ivy and Sandy bridge, respectively

Comment: This isn't necessarily factually accurate, as many OEMs lockout what processors can and cannot be utilized via the BIOS or UEFI firmware, regardless if the motherboard can support it.